# Pyspark iterate through dates to read in data for specific grouping of date, perform some transformations then rewrite to data lake

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

The problem: I have some data in date structured directory in data lake.

I need to pull in this data for each date I need to pull in only the last 5 days e.g. for 1st dec 2022 I would need data for `26/11, 27/11, 28/11 ...1/12.`

I perform some transformations on it then filter the dataframe to only keep the current date records (01/12 in the example above) then send to date structured directory `yyyy/mm/dd` to data lake.

Currently I have two variables defined

```
first_date = datetime(2022,2,20).date()

last_date = datetime(2022,2, 12).date()
```

I then wrote a for loop to iterate through this

The step where I added the comment #run notebook to write to data lake is the step where I need to apply some transformations.

I have currently put those in a separate notebook. Is there a way I can loop through the dates and run the notebook.

So the algorithm in its first iteration would run like this:

First iteration.

```
current_date = 20/02/2023

end_date  = 17/02/2023

files_paths = \['/mnt/container/2022/02/20/\*.parquet', 
'/mnt/container/2022/02/19/\*.parquet', 
'/mnt/container/2022/02/18/\*.parquet', 
'/mnt/container/2022/02/17/\*.parquet'\]
```

In the separate notebook I have code that reads in the files from '`files*paths`',* performs some transformations on it and then ideally.

I would like to filter the dataframe so that only records for the 'current_date' iteration are left (in the first iteration it would be only records for `20/02/2023`.

I have a date column in the parquet files) behind then write to to date structured directory to data lake where the date would be whatever the current_date is equal to in the iteration so in the first iteration it would be written to `2023/02/20` as parquet files.

```
current_date = first_date
while (current_date >= last_date):
    print(current_date, end="\n")
    
    file_paths = []
    end_date = current_date- timedelta(days=3)
    
    for date in (current_date - timedelta(n) for n in range((current_date - end_date).days + 1)):
        file_path = f"/mnt/container/{date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')}/*.parquet"
        file_paths.append(file_path) 
    print(file_paths)
    #run notebook to write to data lake 

    
        
    current_date = current_date - timedelta(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can calculate the `start_date and end_date` values in one notebook and pass them to another notebook.
- I have taken the following code in first notebook:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

first_date = datetime.strptime('2023-02-28', '%Y-%m-%d')
last_date = datetime.strptime('2023-02-20', '%Y-%m-%d')
current_date = first_date
while (current_date >= last_date):
    #print(current_date, end="\n")
    
    file_paths = []
    end_date = current_date- timedelta(days=3)
    
    dbutils.notebook.run("/nb2",60, {"start_date" : current_date, "end_date" : end_date})
    
    current_date = current_date - timedelta(1)
```

- The following is the code that I have taken in 2nd notebook (nb2 from above code).

```
start_date = dbutils.widgets.get("start_date")
end_date = dbutils.widgets.get("end_date")

file_paths = [f"/mnt/container/{single_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')}/*.parquet" for single_date in pd.date_range(end_date, start_date, freq='D')]


#operations you want to perform within date range, start date would be the folder that you want to write the filtered data to
```

- Now, here you can read the entire data into a single dataframe by reading the array `file_paths` as path. You can perform all the required operations on this data. Since you want to filter and store the data in `2023/02/28` folder when the start date is `2023-02-28`, you can build another destination path using the `start_date` variable.
- When I run the first notebook, the dates will be properly iterated. The following is one of the notebook run output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried this code but unfortunately the execution failed or went on for so long I had to stop the run.  Trying this way I can see in the notebook run the parameters are start_date and end_date as 28/02 and 25/02. I need the variables start date and end_date to change for every iteration. will this do that?

Comment: How many dates are you trying to iterate through? If the number is huge, consider using just one notebook (merge the code) and try again

Comment: well I need to iterate through a years worth of data (2022) but I have reduced it to a month / 20/15 days e.g. 27/02/2023 - 20/02/2023 as an example

Comment: try using all the code (similar to the one given) in a single notebook and check again.

Comment: Currently the range of dates I have specified to be last_date = 20/02/23 -  first_date = 27/02/23. For this range of dates (each iteration should be one date in the range) for each iteration 1) get the file paths for the last 3 dates so for the iteration where the counter is at 27/02 file_paths = [27/02, 26/02, 25/02, 24/02] and then pass this to a dataframe and perform some operations and save the dataframe to date structured directory yyyy/mm/dd which should be 2023/02/27

Comment: The above procedure should work. How are you reading the files from `file_paths` array?